# C function to write data with for and scanf

Tags: c, function, scanf

I have a case where if "5" is selected then a function is called to write a field from a struct, in this case the name.

**Variable:**

```
void QuantidadeMusicos (Elementos *elementos);
```

**CASE**

```
case 4:
                QuantidadeMusicos;  
                break;
```

**FUNCTION:**

```
void QuantidadeMusicos (Elementos *elementos) {
for (i=0; i = 10; i++)
{
    //if
    printf ("Elemento %d: %s", i, elementos[i].nome);
}
```

}

**FULL CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch,
    system("pause") or input loop */

//Estrutura para recolher os elementos

typedef struct elementos
{
  char nome [30 + 1];
  int idade;
  char PapelNaBanda [30 + 1];
}Elementos;

//Estrutura para recolher as musicas

typedef struct musicas
{
  char nome [30 + 1];
  int AnoLancamento;
  char album [30 + 1];
}Musicas;

int opcao;
Elementos elemento[1000];
int i,n;
char nomeProcurar[100];
int posicaoEncontrada;
int menuElementos;
void QuantidadeMusicos (Elementos *elementos);
void QuantidadeMusicas (Musicas *musica);
int GetPosicao(int *array, int nomeProcurar, int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  do
  {
    //Menu
    system("cls");
    printf("1 - Inserir elemento\n");
    printf("2 - Alterar elemento\n");
    printf("3 - Remover elemento\n");
    printf("4 - Quantidade de musicos que compoem a banda\n");
    printf("5 - Quantidade de musicas\n");
    printf("6 - Media das idades dos elementos\n");
    printf("7 - Musico mais novo e mais velho\n");
    printf("8 - Pesquisa por elemento (nome)\n");
    printf("9 - Pesquisa de elementos por papel desempenhado na banda\n");
    printf("10 - Relatorio de elementos ordenado ascendentemente pelo nome\n");
    printf("11 - Relatorio de elementos com idade superior a media\n");
    printf("12 - Relatorio de musicas com agrupamento por ano de lancamento\n");
    printf("13 - Relatorio de musicas ordenadas descendentemente pelo nome\n");
    printf("14 - Datas dos concertos\n");
    printf("15 - Despesas e lucros\n");
    printf("Qual a opcao: ?");  
    scanf("%d", &opcao);
    system("cls");


    switch(opcao)
    {
      case 1:
          printf("1- Inserir elemento\n");
          printf("2- Alterar elemento\n");
          printf("1- Remover elemento\n");
          printf("Escolha uma opção:");
          scanf ("%d", &menuElementos);
          system("cls");
          fflush(stdin);

          switch(menuElementos)
          {
            case 1:
                printf("Quantos elementos a inserir: ?");
                scanf("%d", &n);

                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                  printf("Nome do %d elemento: ", i + 1 );
                  fflush(stdin);
                  gets(elemento[i].nome);
                  fflush(stdin);
                  printf("Idade: ");
                  scanf("%d",&elemento[i].idade);
                  fflush(stdin);
                  printf("Papel na banda: ");
                  gets(elemento[i].PapelNaBanda);
                  fflush(stdin);  
                } break;

            case 4:
                QuantidadeMusicos;
                break;

            case 5:
                QuantidadeMusicas;  
                break;  
          }
    }
  }while(opcao != 0);  
} 



int GetPosicao ( int *array, int nomeProcurar, int n)
{
  int posicaoEncontrada = -1, i;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if(array[i] == nomeProcurar)
    {
      posicaoEncontrada = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return posicaoEncontrada;
}

// FUNÇÕES


void QuantidadeMusicos (Elementos *elementos) {
  for (i=0; i = 10; i++)
  {
    //if
    printf ("Elemento %d: %s", i, elementos[i].nome);
  }
}

void QuantidadeMusicas (Musicas *musicas) {
  for (i=0; i = 50; i++)
  {
    // if
    printf ("Elemento %d: %s",i, musicas[i].nome);
  }
}
```

It does nothing.

Comment: Please read a book on C for how to call a C function. Thanks.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `gets()` is dangeroous, use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: `for (i=0; i = 10; i++)` is very strange

Comment: It would be better if the output statements are written in english. Can't understand whats happening.:(

Answer (score 0):

```
case 4:
    QuantidadeMusicos;  
    break;
```

doesn't call the function.

To call the function do

```
case 4:
    QuantidadeMusicos(elemento);  
    break;
```

and also fix:

```
for (i=0; i = 10; i++)  // endless loop !!
```

to be

```
for (i=0; i < 10; i++)  // Loop will repeat 10 times
```